# Making a histogram like summary of the values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got the following price df:

```
datetime
2022-09-07 12:30:00    144.183
2022-09-07 12:35:00    144.184
2022-09-07 12:40:00    144.151
2022-09-07 12:45:00    144.154
2022-09-07 12:50:00    144.144
2022-09-07 12:55:00    144.154
2022-09-07 13:00:00    144.203
Name: High, dtype: float64
```

With a margin of 0.01 of each price point, I want to see if I can downsize this to 3 arrays:

```
a = [144.144]
b = [144.151, 144.154, 144.154]
c = [144.183, 144.184]
d = [144.203]
```

My next step would be to count the array length, creating a strength measurement of the price, so that b = 3, while a = 1.

Finally, I would like to end up with a b starting & end point, such as this:

```
datetime
2022-09-07 12:40:00    144.151
2022-09-07 12:55:00    144.154
Name: High, dtype: float64
```

Got any tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [
            "2022-09-07 12:30:00",
            "2022-09-07 12:35:00",
            "2022-09-07 12:40:00",
            "2022-09-07 12:45:00",
            "2022-09-07 12:50:00",
            "2022-09-07 12:55:00",
            "2022-09-07 13:00:00",
        ],
        "col2": [144.183, 144.184, 144.151, 144.154, 144.144, 144.154, 144.203],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Setup
df["col3"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (round(x["col2"], 2), round(x["col2"] + 0.01, 2)), axis=1
)

# Find arrays
new_df = (
    df[["col2", "col3"]]
    .groupby("col3")
    .agg(list)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .rename(columns={"col2": "group"})
)

# Add length
new_df["count"] = new_df["group"].apply(len)

# Add start and end points
new_df["start"] = new_df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[df["col2"] == min(x["group"]), "col1"].values[0], axis=1
)
new_df["end"] = new_df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[df["col2"] == max(x["group"]), "col1"].values[0], axis=1
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
                         group  count                start  \
0                    [144.144]      1  2022-09-07 12:50:00   
1  [144.151, 144.154, 144.154]      3  2022-09-07 12:40:00   
2           [144.183, 144.184]      2  2022-09-07 12:30:00   
3                    [144.203]      1  2022-09-07 13:00:00   

                   end  
0  2022-09-07 12:50:00  
1  2022-09-07 12:45:00  
2  2022-09-07 12:35:00  
3  2022-09-07 13:00:00
```